# what types of equipment do i need to rapidly produce songs with keyboard instrumentation, USB microphone vocals, and multi-track recording?

Tags: recording, midi, keyboard, software, homerecording

I'm confused about the "tools" I need and what all is done by the synthesizer workstation vs laptop software.

I will create percussion and rhythm tracks with a keyboard synthesizer, do quantization, then multi-track record midi instruments and audio lead/harmony vocals with USB mic, then mix and generate an audio file for upload to YouTube etc.

I have 10 songs ready to produce and have amateur experience recording and multi-tracking rock band genre back in the days of my good ol' Fostex 4-tracker, Roland drum machine, and Casio synth.

Comment: Does this answer your question? It doesn't address the mic, but there's some good advice there. [In electronic music equipment and software, what are some good ways of cutting costs without sacrificing quality/effort?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/17062/in-electronic-music-equipment-and-software-what-are-some-good-ways-of-cutting-c)

Comment: My vague advice to these kinds of questions is "start simple, and when you realize you're lacking something, add it." You need nothing but a computer to start. You could even make demo-quality recordings with a laptop's internal microphone. The mic is probably the first place to upgrade; don't assume it has to be a USB model; instead, you might want an "interface" that plugs in via USB and accepts XLR, then you can choose a good starter studio mic.

Comment: But invest time and effort in accumulating hardware only *after* investing in musical quality and creativity. A crappy recording of great music is great; a great recording of crappy music is crappy. Don't let lack of gear keep you from getting started.

Comment: Look up some articles about how Billie Eillish and her brother Phineas created a Grammy winning album essentially in his bedroom. You don’t necessarily *need* anything. Maybe you want to find a producer to work with who both has some stuff and already knows how to use it.

Answer (score 5):

This is really far too broad to cover in a few paragraphs, so let's just hit the basics…

*Oh… one thing this is not going to be is **rapid***.
You are not going to learn this stuff in a week or even a month. It's like saying, "I want to be a pilot" & expecting to have your wings by next weekend.

The 'keyboard workstation' is out of vogue these days, since you can do it all with a single DAW [Digital Audio Workstation… what they used to call a sequencer] & a shed-load of plugins for soft synths [commonly called VSTi, whatever the plugin type actually is].
You will need a keyboard 'controller' - basically just something to generate the midi notes that the rest of your system will play back.

The first thing you'll need is a computer with a lot of 'grunt'. People do do this on laptops, but it's a bit like trying to get a double bed in a mini, when you really need a van or a truck.
[Opinions will vary on this, but to my mind the less powerful your computer, the more time you'll spend working around getting it to play everything all at once & more time on tweaking, bouncing & finagling the machine rather than getting on with the job.]

Whichever DAW you choose you'll find as many people hate it as love it - it's down to personal choice. Big hitters are Cubase* or Logic, with perhaps Ableton or Reaper following along behind.
These all tend to come with some fairly decent synths & effects plugins these days, so splash out on "the good stuff" only after you understand the "free stuff".

Synths - you can get almost anything you used to get in hardware, in software. Look at [Arturia](https://www.arturia.com/products#software-instruments,software-instruments-effects) for a huge selection for starters, from an old Wurlitzer or Rhodes piano, Hammond B3, ARP 2600, DX7, Synclavier… you name it, they got it.
There are also a myriad [by more companies that anyone could list] which are not based on anything that ever existed in hardware.

No-one can choose a mic for you. No good buying one for podcasts to do 'proper' vocals. First you need to know what you want & why - see https://www.sweetwater.com/insync/studio-microphone-buying-guide/ for a guide then you need to hear some… https://www.sweetwater.com/feature/vocal-mic-shootout/

Same for audio interfaces - https://www.thomann.de/gb/usb_audio_interfaces.html - one for every budget.

Studio monitors - not even going to start on those.

You can see from this very brief intro that you need to research each aspect - no-one can simply point you at one of each & say "Go".

Once you start to accumulate your gear… then there's just the job of learning how to use it…
…you're really not going to do that in a weekend ;)

*Cubase comes in several variants, from 'beginner' to 'I earn my living doing this'. Logic has a baby brother, freeware Garage Band, but is Mac only. The others I don't know so well.

Comment: Ableton Live has definitely made inroads, and one could produce great electronic music using only the included synths, samples, and effects that come with Logic, Cubase, or Live. Not that I don’t own a lot of third party stuff, but maybe would suggest a beginner get up to speed on the included stuff before spending more money.

Comment: @ToddWilcox - yeah, but it's one of those things I looked at once & couldn't be bothered with; compared to that I've been using Cubase since the mid 80s. I also was forced to use Logic for several years through the 90s. The rest I don't really know at all. Call me an old stick-in-the-mud ;)) [I've already added 'learn the free stuff first'] *repost for dumb typo ;))*